# Binding custom params to strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a form_for which calls to a create method.

The create method is fairly typical, it calls a neighbouring method which houses the strong params:

```
Params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body, :user_id, :access)
```

I create the record then with the following:

```
Blog.create(blog_params)
```

Though before I do that, I run a helper method which determines the value of `:access` - I assign the helper method directly to `params[:access]` as shown:

```
params[:access] = myHelper(val1, val2)
```

But this doesn't work, it just stays as a `nil` value. Currently, I'm having to do the following:

```
Blog.create(blog_params).update(access: params[:access])
```

Which is rather ugly and even dysfunctional when it comes to updating a record. What can I do to keep it tidy?

Answer (score 0):

Your `:access` param actually lives in `params[:blog][:access]` before calling `params.require(:blog)`

So use:

```
params[:blog][:access] = myHelper(val1, val2)
```

Or:

```
bparams = blog_params
bparams[:access] = blog_params
Blog.create(bparams)
```